# PrimeFactorizater Java

Tags: java

I've been working on this program for a while, this is the last of my first assignment.

I am experiencing the following error and I am not sure how to proceed. Please keep in mind that I am new to Java so I might have messed something up.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Homework1.Q5.PrimeFactorizer.toString(PrimeFactorizer.java:104)
at Homework1.Q5.PrimeFactorTest.main(PrimeFactorTest.java:19)
```

I originally had most of the algorithm in getFactorsAndExponents, but the professor responded that it needed to be in compute. He also mentioned that I do not create the ArrayLists. I tried to rectify that and this is what I have now. I still get the above error when I input my value.

```
package Homework1.Q5;

import java.util.*;

public class PrimeFactorizer {

      private int n;
      private ArrayList<Integer> primes;
      private ArrayList<Integer> exponents;
      private ArrayList<Integer> primesandexponents;



      /** 
       * Initialize the object with target number n. 
       */
      public PrimeFactorizer(int n) {
        n = 0;

      } 

      /**
       * Return n, the target number.
       */


      public int getN() {
        return n;
      }

      /**
       * Compute factorization. Do not repeat operation if it was called before.
       */
      public void compute() {

          getN();

          int largestPrimeFactor = 1;

          for(int i = 2; i <= n/i;){
              if(n % i == 0){
                  largestPrimeFactor = i;
                  //shrink n
                  n /= i;
                  //A prime factor was found so added to primes.
                  //first we check if it is in the array already
                  searchArray(i,primes);
                  if(i < 0){
                      primes.add(largestPrimeFactor);
                      exponents.add(1);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      addExponentArray(i, exponents);
                  }    
              }
              else
              {
                  i++;
              }

          }
          if(largestPrimeFactor < n)
          {
              //This is where the largest prime factor will be, also added to primes
              largestPrimeFactor = n;
              primes.add(largestPrimeFactor);
          }

      }

      /**
       * Return the factors and exponents in two arraylists. Call compute() first, if necessary.
       * For instance, if n=60, primes=[2,3,5], and exponents=[2,1,1].
       */
      public void getFactorsAndExponents(int n, ArrayList<Integer> primes, ArrayList<Integer> exponents) {

          compute();

          ArrayList<Integer> primesandexponents = new ArrayList<Integer>();

          for(int i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++){
              int value = primes.get(i);
              primesandexponents.add(value);
              int eValue = exponents.get(i);
              primesandexponents.add(eValue);

          } 

      }
      /**
       * Return a string with the "pretty" representation of the prime factorization.
       * For instance, if n is 60, then toString() for the PrimeFactorizer(60) object
       * should be "60 = 2^2*3*5". Call compute() if not done before.
       */
      public String toString()
      {

          String finalOutput = "";

          finalOutput = finalOutput + n + " = ";
          //System.out.print(n + " = ");

          for(int i = 0; i < primesandexponents.size() - 1; i++){

              if(i % 2 == 1){
                  int value = primesandexponents.get(i);
                  if(value > 1)
                  {
                      finalOutput += "^";
                      finalOutput += value;
                  }

              }
              else{
                 int value = primesandexponents.get(i);
                 finalOutput += value; 
                 finalOutput += "*";
              }
          }

              finalOutput(finalOutput);
              return finalOutput;
      }

        // other code, helper functions, etc.

      public void finalOutput(String finalOutput){
          System.out.println(finalOutput);


      }
      public void addExponentArray(int index, ArrayList<Integer> exponents){
            //get the value in the array using the index found with searcharray
            int value = exponents.get(index);
            //increment value to indicate an added exponent
            value++;
            //set the index to value
            exponents.set(index, value);
      }

      public int searchArray(int i, ArrayList<Integer> primes){
         int isInArray = 0;
         for(int j = 0; j < primes.size(); j++)
         {
            int value = primes.get(j);
            if(value == i)
            {
                isInArray = i;  
            }
            else
            {
                isInArray = -1;
            }
         }
         return isInArray;

      }





}

package Homework1.Q5;

import java.util.*;

public class PrimeFactorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a number which you would like the Prime Factorization of:");

        int n = in.nextInt();
        PrimeFactorizer obj = new PrimeFactorizer(n);

        ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> exponents = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        obj.getFactorsAndExponents(n, primes, exponents);

        obj.toString();




    }

}
```

Thank you very much again for any help.

Comment: Your constructor seems rather odd - you pass `n` to it, but ignore the value and set `n = 0;`, try to replace this with `this.n = n;`

Comment: Done, that makes sense, something I might have made a mistake with going back to the earlier assignment.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Homework1.Q5.PrimeFactorizer.searchArray(PrimeFactorizer.java:144)
 at Homework1.Q5.PrimeFactorizer.compute(PrimeFactorizer.java:47)
 at Homework1.Q5.PrimeFactorizer.getFactorsAndExponents(PrimeFactorizer.java:78)
 at Homework1.Q5.PrimeFactorTest.main(PrimeFactorTest.java:17)

Seems to have something to do with the ArrayLists now.

Comment: Your general problem is your arguments are the same names as your fields. You do seem to be a bit confused about the roles of arguments and fields.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the ArrayList fields in the constructor e.g.

```
public PrimeFactorizer(int n) {
    this.n = n;
    primes = new ArrayList<>();
    exponents = new ArrayList<>();
    primesandexponents = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Otherwise they will be `null`. The `n` member is 0 by default. You probably want to set it to the constructor's argument.

These constructor modifications will resolve the `NullPointerException` only. As others have commented you need to study on the difference of  members (fields), function arguments and local variables.

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't sure what to do there.

Now I am getting

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 primes cannot be resolved to a variable
 exponents cannot be resolved to a variable

 at Homework1.Q5.PrimeFactorTest.main(PrimeFactorTest.java:16)**

in main

Comment: Just compiled your code with the constructor in my answer and no other changes. I don't see this error. I do get a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` at `addExponentArray` function

Comment: Ya I started to get that problem as well, I made a bunch of changes and I have it working now, thank you very much though